# Class not found exception for mapper class when using map reduce with accumulo

Tags: java, accumulo

I am new to accumulo and trying to write a word count program using mapreduce and accumulo.

I have followed the [accumulo git hub for mapreduce](https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/examples/simple/mapreduce/TokenFileWordCount.java) to write the code and kept the input file in hdfs

But when I tried to execute it, it is giving exception as $Map class not found

Below is my code snippet for map class

```
package mapreducepackageforaccumulo;

import java.io.IOException; 


 import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ClientConfiguration; 
 import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat; 
 import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.security.tokens.PasswordToken;
 import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Mutation; 
 import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Value; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool; 
 import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner; 
 import org.slf4j.Logger; 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 


 /** 
  * A simple map reduce job that inserts word counts into accumulo.   
  */ 
 public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool { 


   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WordCount.class); 


   public static class WordCountMapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Mutation> { 

         public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context output) throws IOException, InterruptedException  { 

           log.info("Inside accumulo word count mapper");
           String[] words = value.toString().split("\\s+");  

           for (String word : words) {  

             Mutation mutation = new Mutation(new Text(word)); 
             mutation.put(new Text("count"), new Text("20080906"), new Value("1".getBytes())); 
             output.write(null, mutation);           
           } 
         } 
       } 


   @Override 
   public int run(String[] args) throws Exception { 

     String input = args[0]; 
     CreateConnection createConnection = new CreateConnection();
     createConnection.setUser(args[1]);
     createConnection.setPassword(args[2]);
     String table = "wordcountTable";

     Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf()); 
     job.setJobName(WordCount.class.getName()); 
     job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class); 
     //job.setJar("WordCount.jar");


     job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class); 
     TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, input); 

     System.out.println("user.....  " +createConnection.getUser() + " pass.... " +createConnection.getPassword() + " path.... " + args[0]);


     job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapClass.class);
     job.setNumReduceTasks(0); 

     job.setOutputFormatClass(AccumuloOutputFormat.class); 
     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class); 
     job.setOutputValueClass(Mutation.class); 


     // AccumuloInputFormat not used here, but it uses the same functions. 
     AccumuloOutputFormat.setZooKeeperInstance(job, ClientConfiguration.loadDefault().withInstance(createConnection.getInstanceName()).withZkHosts(createConnection.getZooServers())); 
     AccumuloOutputFormat.setConnectorInfo(job, createConnection.getUser(), new PasswordToken(createConnection.getPassword())); 
     AccumuloOutputFormat.setCreateTables(job, true); 
     AccumuloOutputFormat.setDefaultTableName(job, table); 


     job.waitForCompletion(true); 
     return 0; 
   } 


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
     int res = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args); 
     System.exit(res); 
   } 
 }
```

Previously I used to get class not found exception for LimitInputStream.
So I changed the guava jar file to that of the jar we are using in hadoop i:e guava-11.0.2.jar

Below is the stack trace

```
    [supriti@bhucloud01 ~]$ accumulo jar  /home/supriti/Javajars/wordcount.jar /Supr                                                                                        iti/new.txt supriti supriti123
user.....  supriti pass.... supriti123 path.... /Supriti/new.txt
2015-08-13 11:29:07,694 [client.RMProxy] INFO : Connecting to ResourceManager at bhucloud01.ad.infosys.com/10.118.192.109:8032
2015-08-13 11:29:08,789 [mapreduce.JobSubmitter] WARN : No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2015-08-13 11:29:08,808 [input.FileInputFormat] INFO : Total input paths to process : 1
2015-08-13 11:29:09,270 [mapreduce.JobSubmitter] INFO : number of splits:1
2015-08-13 11:29:09,487 [mapreduce.JobSubmitter] INFO : Submitting tokens for job: job_1439440228760_0006
2015-08-13 11:29:09,817 [mapred.YARNRunner] INFO : Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
2015-08-13 11:29:09,919 [impl.YarnClientImpl] INFO : Submitted application application_1439440228760_0006
2015-08-13 11:29:09,997 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : The url to track the job: http://bhucloud01.ad.infosys.com:8088/proxy/application_1439440228760_0006/
2015-08-13 11:29:09,999 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Running job: job_1439440228760_0006
2015-08-13 11:29:23,320 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Job job_1439440228760_0006 running in uber mode : false
2015-08-13 11:29:23,322 [mapreduce.Job] INFO :  map 0% reduce 0%
2015-08-13 11:29:27,426 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Task Id : attempt_1439440228760_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mapreducepackageforaccumulo.WordCount$WordCountMapClass not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mapreducepackageforaccumulo.WordCount$WordCountMapClass not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1953)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2045)
        ... 8 more

2015-08-13 11:29:35,544 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Task Id : attempt_1439440228760_0006_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mapreducepackageforaccumulo.WordCount$WordCountMapClass not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mapreducepackageforaccumulo.WordCount$WordCountMapClass not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1953)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2045)
        ... 8 more

2015-08-13 11:29:41,604 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Task Id : attempt_1439440228760_0006_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mapreducepackageforaccumulo.WordCount$WordCountMapClass not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class mapreducepackageforaccumulo.WordCount$WordCountMapClass not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1953)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2045)
        ... 8 more

2015-08-13 11:29:47,657 [mapreduce.Job] INFO :  map 100% reduce 0%
2015-08-13 11:29:47,672 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Job job_1439440228760_0006 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1439440228760_0006_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

2015-08-13 11:29:47,866 [mapreduce.Job] INFO : Counters: 9
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=29516
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=14758
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=14758
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=30224384
```

Comment: First, make sure your import is from `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` and not `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper` ... that has stumped me before. Secondly, where is your `run` method? Are you setting the mapper class?

Comment: The full Tool implementation and how you're invoking that Tool would be necessary to debug why you're having issues here.

Comment: Thanks all. @Tgsmith61591 I am using org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper. I have edited my question and gave the full code that I am using

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of your exception

Comment: Hi @RC. I have added the stack trace

Comment: We are using Cloudera manager to manage the accumulo instance

Comment: Hi all, thanks to all of you for your valuable time.
I am able to solve the problem it seems there was some issue with cloudera manager .
When we restarted the whole service the execution went fine :)